# How to access Master page from a non-child page

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

Is it possible to access controls on the master page from another page which is not a child of the Master?

Specifically, I have a LogIn page. If the user has a certain role, I want to enable or disable MenuItems on the master. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In your case, since master page does not have an instance, you can not access that non existent instance.
2. If you want to manage the menu items on user basis, you sould create the menu item data dynamically depending on the user role, etc. Also, you can achieve the same functionality via javascript by hiding/showing some menu elements (since this will be on client side, you should probably not use this alternative)
3. You may create menu items data and store it in Session (session is per user), and when user navigates to a page with that master page, in master page's code, you may use that manu items data in session, to create menu specific to that user.